# ATC-605-UB11 Boot issues

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I disabled *SecureBoot* and cleaned my Win 10 previous installation on this machine prior to attempting to switch to Ubuntu 14.04 in order to install Security Onion. I shoud preface this with the fact that this computer came with win 8 preinstalled and i had upgraded to win 10 when it came out. now I would like to install security onion on it for an ids.

However, I only get booting to a black screen. The HDD is a GPT partition. I attempted a grub bootloader repair. But the black screen issue still persists. Using <kbd>F12</kbd> only ever brings up the option to use the bootable USB. The HDD labeled Ubuntu is seen by the BIOS, but it only boots up to a black screen.

I'm really unsure after spending two days trying out various guides including the "UEFI by Ubuntu" guide.